# Understanding Interfaces C#

Tags: c#, oop, interface, encapsulation

Been reading all day on interfaces and abstract classes trying to get a grasp on them to better understand the amazon library I'm working with.  I have this code:

```
using MWSClientCsRuntime;

namespace MarketplaceWebServiceOrders.Model
{
    public interface IMWSResponse : IMwsObject
    {
        ResponseHeaderMetadata ResponseHeaderMetadata { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
namespace MWSClientCsRuntime
{
    public interface IMwsObject
    {
        void ReadFragmentFrom(IMwsReader r);
        string ToXML();
        string ToXMLFragment();
        void WriteFragmentTo(IMwsWriter w);
        void WriteTo(IMwsWriter w);
    }
}
```

My first questions is I thought Interfaces cannot contain fields, however they can contain properties usch as `ResponseHeaderMetadata`?

Second, in my main program I have this line of code:

```
IMWSResponse response = null;
```

with `response` being later used to store the information that amazon sends back after a method call is invoked.  **But what is the meaning behind setting a variable of an interface type to null?**

Also, a interface can implement another interface?  It isn't only classes that can implement interfaces, but interfaces themselves as well?

Comment: What do you mean what does it mean to set the variable to null?  It's not any different than any other variable being set to null; it means it doesn't actually point to anything.  What don't you understand about it?

Comment: What's the point of setting a variable type to an interface?  I understanding setting a variable to a string, or an int or other data type, but when would I need to set a variable to an interface type.

Comment: Sounds like you need to spend some time reading an intro programming book, or something equivalent.  That's well beyond the scope of an SO question.

Comment: Abstraction!!! Because system should depend on declaration and not on implementation. That's how loosely coupled systems are designed. Here's  a [post](http://www.cshandler.com/2015/12/abstract-class-vs-interface-in-oo.html) to understand the basics of Interfaces vs Abstract classes.

Comment: Ah okay I also think I had a little light bulb moment too.  The method to retrieve information from Amazon has a return type called `ListOrdersResponse` and this class implements `IMWSResponse`, so this is the reason the variable `response` can be used to store the information returned from the amazon method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pproperties can be present in interfaces since properties are actually methods - the use of `T GetSomeValue()` alongside `void SetSomeValue(T value)` became so common in other languages, that C# implements these as properties.

The meaning behind setting an interface member to `null` is the same as setting anyother property to `null` - since a property's `set` accessor is a method, it's like calling any other method on the interface. What `null` means where is up to the implementation.

Interfaces do not *implement* each other, since and interface cannot contain code and therefore is not implementing; Interface inheritance allows one to require one interface in another. A big example is [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx), which is so closely tied to [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) that it inherits, thus meaning any class implementing `IEnumerable<T>` must also implement `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

An interface is like a contractual agreement. By inheriting an interface from a class, you are saying, "I agree to implement all of the methods defined in this interface". So if you have an interface like this:

```
public interface IWorker    {
    void DoWork();
}
```

and you use that interface like this:

```
public class Employee : IWorker
{
    // you are forced to implement this method
    void DoWork {}
}

public class Contractor: IWorker
{
    // you are forced to implement this method
    void DoWork {}
}
```

By "inheriting" interfaces by other interfaces, you are simply agreeing to implement any methods in the other interfaces, like so (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664594(v=vs.71).aspx)):

```
interface IBase
{
   void F();
}
interface IDerived: IBase
{
   void G();
}
class C: IDerived
{
   void IBase.F() {...}
   void IDerived.G() {...}
}
class D: C, IDerived
{
   public void F() {...}
   public void G() {...}
}
```

You do not have to set a variable of an interface type to null, though you have the power to do so. The great thing about interfaces is that you are able to set a variable of the type of interface, to anything that "inherits" that interface.